# Resolver function doesn't return anything

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

In my resolver function I have loop that call http service in each itaration:

```
function detailedReportDataResolver($stateParams, reportService) {
    var promises = [];
    var frequenciesArr = $stateParams.frequencies.split(',').map(function (item) { return parseInt(item, 10); });

     angular.forEach(frequenciesArr, function (freq, key) {
         reportService.getDetailsReport($stateParams.clientId, $stateParams.date, freq).then(function (result) {
             promises.push(result.data);
        });
     });
     return $q.all(promises);         
}
```

Here how I call the resolver function in my module:

```
  resolve: {
    detailedReportData: ["$stateParams", "reportService", detailedReportDataResolver]
      }
```

Here is service:

```
(function () {
    "use strict";

    angular.module("reportBuilder").factory("reportService", ["$http", "config", reportService]);

    function reportService($http, config) {
        var serviceUrl = config.baseUrl + "api/Reports/";
        var service = {
            getDetailsReport: detailsReport
        };

        return service;


        function detailsReport(clientId, date, frequencies) {

            if (!date && !clientId) return null;
            return $http.get(serviceUrl + "ReportDetailed/" + clientId + "/" + date + "/" + frequencies);
        }

    }
})();
```

I need to wait for http service to finish before starting next iteration of loop and the return the result. For this purpose I use `$q.all` in resolver finction above.

But resolver function doesn't return anything.Any idea what I do wrong?Why resolver function doesn't returns anything?

Answer (score 0):

Array of promise is not composed correctly. Can you try:

```
function detailedReportDataResolver($stateParams, reportService) {
    var promises = [];
    var frequenciesArr = $stateParams.frequencies.split(',').map(function (item) { return parseInt(item, 10); });

     angular.forEach(frequenciesArr, function (freq, key) {
         var promise = reportService.getDetailsReport($stateParams.clientId, $stateParams.date, freq).then(function (result) {
             return result.data;
        });
        promises.push(promise);
     });
     return $q.all(promises);         
}
```

Comment: thank you I tryed your way but still the function not returns data fatched  by http servicve